# Sorting on nested object in elastic search, failed to find nested object under path

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following 2 documents indexed.

```json
{
      region: 'US',
      manager: {
        age: 30,
        name: {
          first: 'John',
          last: 'Smith',
        },
      },
    },
{
      region: 'US',
      manager: {
        age: 30,
        name: {
          first: 'John',
          last: 'Cena',
        },
      },
    }
```

I am trying to search and sort them by their last name. I have tried the following query.

```json
{
      sort: [
        {
          'manager.name.first': {
            order: 'desc',
            nested: {
              path: 'manager.name.first',
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      query: {
        match: {
          'manager.name.first': 'John',
        },
      },
    },
```

I am getting the following error in response. What am I doing wrong here (I am very new to this elasticsearch, so apologize if this is a very basic thing I am not aware of)

`ResponseError: search_phase_execution_exception: [query_shard_exception] Reason: [nested] failed to find nested object under path [manager.name.first]`

I also tried `path: 'manager.name',` but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use only `manager` as nested path as that is only field define as `nested` type.

```json
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "manager.name.first.keyword": {
        "order": "desc",
        "nested": {
          "path": "manager"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Use `manager.name.first` as field name if it is defined as `keyword` type otherwise use `manager.name.first.keyword` if it is define as multi type field with `text` and  `keyword` both.